# pandas read_json throws malloc error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file containing json array with 3861935 lines.

```
df = pandas.read_json('xyz.json')
Python(20436,0x7fff74109310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff533bdec0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

It works fine with R jsonlite's fromJSON()